How to Fix "Unsafe Object Binding" in Spring Boot with DTO to Entity Mapping?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I'm directly binding incoming JSON requests to DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) using @RequestBody. During a security review, I was flagged for the "Unsafe Object Binding" vulnerability because my DTOs map directly to entities, potentially allowing malicious input or over-binding.
Controller Code:
    @PostMapping("/createDetails")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createDetails(@Valid @RequestBody MyEntityDTO myEntityDTO) {
        log.debug("Inside createDetails method, DTO - {}", myEntityDTO);

        Integer userId = userService.getLoggedInUserId();
        myEntityDTO.setUserId(userId);

        myEntityService.saveEntity(myEntityDTO.toEntity());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Entity Created Successfully");
}

DTO Class:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
public class MyEntityDTO {

    private Integer entityId;
    private String entityName;
    private Integer entityNumber;
    private String status;
    private List<MySubEntityDTO> subEntities;

    @JsonIgnore
    public MyEntity toEntity(@NonNull Integer userId) {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.setEntityId(this.entityId);
        myEntity.setEntityName(this.entityName != null ? this.entityName : "UNASSIGNED");
        myEntity.setEntityNumber(this.entityNumber);
        myEntity.setStatus(this.status);
        myEntity.setUserId(userId);

        MyEntityRelation relation = new MyEntityRelation();
        relation.setStatus("ACTIVE");
        relation.setSubEntities(this.subEntities != null ? this.subEntities.stream()
                .map(MySubEntityDTO::toEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()) : null);
        relation.setMyEntity(myEntity);

        myEntity.setRelations(relation);
        return myEntity;
    }
}

Entity Class (Simplified):
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer entityId;
    private String entityName;
    private Integer entityNumber;
    private String status;
    private Integer userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MyEntityRelation> relations;

    // Getters, Setters, and Named Queries...
}

Issue:
The vulnerability arises because direct binding of user inputs to DTOs and converting them to entities may allow an attacker to inject unexpected values, bypass validation, or manipulate sensitive fields like status or userId
What I've Tried So Far:

I added @Valid to the DTO and field-level validation annotations.
I ignored sensitive fields like userId using @JsonIgnore.


You should have this conversation with reviewers. Only they know exact criteria for this problem.

yes Correct but the reviewers only care about the vulnerability count , Help me if you can suggest something from your side ?

How do they count vulnerability? If they use some kind of software you may consult it's documentation.
